# The hidden question

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Hidden in this puzzle is a question. Solve the puzzle, find the question, and please answer it!

I leave you with a text file:

```
QW++

 - -
|\|/|
 - -
|/|\|
 - -

###    ###    ##
##  # #    # ###
###     ##   ###
   # #     #    
  #  # # #  #   
###   #  #  ####
  #   ####   #  
   # #     #    
###   #  #  ####
###    ###    ##
###   ####  #   
##  # #    # ###
###     ##   ###
###   ####
```

**Hint 1**:

> Look at the symbol under the QW++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My first thought was "`QW++`... hmm. That's probably QW as in QWERTY.

The sixteen-segment display is a big hint. What about the spaces and octothorps?

The rows represent a digit/symbol. I get:

> EDSYKQHYQERDSP

This looks like it could be four words. Perhaps (3,4,3,4)?

Moving each left on a QWERTY keyboard by the index of the letter in its word gets

> WASTHISTOOEASY
>  Was this too easy?

No, this was actually a bit difficult. I'd be curious to see how you constructed this.

Comment: Oh nice well done!! How did you get the digits/symbols, I'm a little confused?

Comment: Read the segments left to right because the rows are left to right. A # is a 1, a space is a 0. Turn the corresponding segments on and voilà!

Comment: Nice solve! Wow.

Comment: >! I think I get what you're saying, why aren't the Ss transformed?

Comment: It looks to me that rot13(gur gjb F'f va lbhe vavgvny nafjre fgevat fubhyq npghnyyl or T'f.). It also looks like the rot13(gur BC znqr n zvfgnxr jvgu gur frpbaq 'R' va guvf fgevat, naq vg fubhyq or n 'J'.).

Comment: @LannyStrack, looks like those errors to me...

Answer (score 7):

**Partial**

The symbol underneath the QW++ is

> a 16-segment display

and the grid below indicates

> which bits to lit, in lexicographic order.

It reads

> EDSYKQHYQERDSP

Which I still can't turn into a question at the moment...

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

> There are 16 hashes and spaces in each row. Splitting each row in half the hashed could represent 1 and a space 0.

Doing so:

> Here is the binary string:
>
> ```
> 1110000111000011
> 1100101000010111
> 1110000011000111
> 0001010000010000
> 0010010101001000
> 1110001001001111
> 0010001111000100
> 0001010000010000
> 1110001001001111
> 1110000111000011
> 1110001111001000
> 1100101000010111
> 1110000011000111
> 1110001111000000
> ```

Now if we convert it:

> We get a string of numbers. The binary doesn’t seem to be ASCII, but the numbers go as following:
>
> 225, 195
> 202, 23
> 224, 199
> 20, 16
> 37, 72
> 226, 79
> 35, 196
> 20, 16
> 226, 79
> 225, 195
> 227, 200
> 202, 23
> 224, 199
> 227, 192

Notes:

> - There are a couple of the number pairs that appear twice, maybe this is a form of a substitution cipher?
>  - The numbers mostly seem to sit in a particular range, with a few outliers
>  - Perhaps 20,16 represents a space?
>  - Perhaps the ‘QW++’ at the start of the puzzle represents a qwerty keyboard?

Comment: Nice logic, but not the right path. Hint: symbol under `QW++`?

Comment: @mereybot yeah I saw the 16 and set my mind to binary, the actual answer is much better! :)

Comment: Edit: mer**r**ybot :)